# Proof explanation of integral depending on parameter is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, proof-explanation

Here's an extract from my lecture notes which I don't understand. A more general statement and proof is given in:

Paltineanu, G., Bucur, I., Zamfir, M. (2022). Integrals Depending on Parameter. In: Integral Calculus for Engineers. Springer, Singapore. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-981-19-4793-3_4

Anyway,

> Theorem: Assume $f$ is continuous in $K\times E$, where $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact and $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ any interval. Then the function $I: E \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ defined by $$ I(s)=\int_K f(x,s) \mathrm{d}x$$ is continuous in $E$.

> Proof: We may assume $E$ is compact and hence also $K\times E$. Moreover, $f$ is uniformly continuous in $K\times E$. Therefor, for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta(\epsilon)>0$ such that $|x-y|+|s-t|<\delta \implies |f(x,s)-f(y,t)|<\epsilon$ for $(x,s),(y,t)\in K\times E$. In particular
> $$|I(s)-I(s_0)|<\int_K |f(x,s)-f(x,s_0)|\mathrm{d}x\leq\mathrm{sup}_{x\in K}|f(x,s)-f(x,s_0)|\int_K \mathrm{d}x<C\epsilon, \tag{1} $$
> if $|s-s_0|<\delta(\epsilon)$ and $s,s_0\in E$. This shows that $I(s)$ is continuous.

Why can we assume $E$ is compact? It seems like the proof depends on compactness of $E$. Moreover, I'd be grateful if someone could clarify the second and third inequality in $(1)$? I guess the first inequality follows from $\left|\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm{d}x\right|\leq\int_a^b |f(x)|\mathrm{d}x$. The second inequality must simply follow from $|f(x,s)-f(x,s_0)| \leq \mathrm{sup}_{x\in K}|f(x,s)-f(x,s_0)|$, for $s,s_0$ fixed. The third inequality confuses me since by uniform continuity we only have $|f(x,s)-f(x,s_0)|< \epsilon$. Why does $\mathrm{sup}_{x\in K} |f(x,s)-f(x,s_0)| <\epsilon$, which I assume is what the last inequality states?

Comment: Continuouty is a local property, fix $s\in E$ and take a small enough closed interval $I$ so that $s\in I \subseteq E$. As for your other question notice that $|f(x,s)-f(x,s_0)|< \epsilon$ hoksa for every $x$ so the bound for the supremum holds.

Comment: The supremum is the least upper bound, $\varepsilon$ is an upper bound.

Comment: Got it! Thank you.